# How to pass a list to a CSV writer in python and make it write each element in individual cells

Tags: python, csv

This doesn't seem to be answered exactly anywhere and I am working on a project involving it. Using the csv functionality of python, I am attempting to pass a list into the writer.writerow function. I am doing it like so:

```
    zippedTitles = zip(*allTitles)
    zippedTexts = zip(*allText)
    theAllZip = zip(zippedTitles, zippedTexts)

    with open(path, 'a', newline='', encoding='utf8') as file:
        file.write('\ufeff')
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(["","EN","ES","RU","PT-BR","KO","JA","IT","DE","FR","CT","CS"])
        writer.writerow(["#"])
        for diffTitle, diffBody in theAllZip:
            
            writer.writerow(["Name", list(diffTitle)])
            writer.writerow(["Image 1"])
            writer.writerow(["Image 2"])
            writer.writerow(["Body", list(diffBody)])
            writer.writerow("")
            writer.writerow("#")
```

basically, within zippedTitles and zippedTexts are the titles of webpages in each of the languages listed and then the text on those pages in those languages. When I write "list(diffTitle)" I am trying to add each element of that list into the next cell respectively. I know that a comma is the common delimiter. Is there an easy way to do this? Currently, the result is as follows:

[image: What the CSV looks like]

with the entire list being inserted into a single cell. I would write each cell individually and iterate over the list, but it seems CSV only has writerow functionality. Anyways, long story short, is there a way to give a list to the row writer and have it write out the list in individual cells over the row?

Comment: The key is writerow takes a single list where each element Is a cell, so if you have a list as a list element, it ends up entirely in one cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
            writer.writerow(["Name"] + list(diffTitle)])
            writer.writerow(["Image 1"])
            writer.writerow(["Image 2"])
            writer.writerow(["Body"] + list(diffBody)])
```

Are "diffTitle" and "diffBody" already lists?

Comment: That's it! Thanks. They are currently zipped lists, I didn't know whether I needed to unzip them to read through or not. I zipped them up together to iterate over them in parallel, and each one is zipped individually because they were compiled of other lists zipped into a more useful order for me. I will accept your answer in a few minutes when Stack allows me to. Thanks again!